# Create New Spreadsheet from List Rows Present in Table

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have this Microsoft Form end users complete each week. The responses from this form are populated into an Excel file stored in SharePoint, creating a database of sorts. Each week, I'd like to generate a report that contains rows that are equal to a specific date. I'd like this report to be in Excel format because it will need to be emailed to others within my organization.

Here's what I've tried so far:
I created a manual flow that asks the user to input the date for the report they would like to pull. I then have a List rows present in table that has a filter query equal to the date entered by the user when manually triggering the flow. I tried creating an HTML table and then populating the outputs into an excel sheet by using the "create a file" action and making the file contents the HTML table output, but when I ran the flow, I was unable to open the file because it was unsupported by Excel. I'm guessing it's because the table is in HTML and I was trying to put it in a .xlsx file.

Is there a way for me to take the outputs of the list rows present in a table and create a new file each time the flow is run? I was thinking the "Create a Table" action, but I'm not sure that meets the need as I need to already have a file that I want to add the table to. Is there a way I could meet the goal of: run flow ---> filter from database --> create new spreadsheet with results from the filter? Is there something I'm missing/not thinking of?